Huffman's algorithm produces a compressed file that is larger than the original one
I have written this function. It does some magic with the file that I input (the one to compress) - a .txt (text) file, however the output (compressed) file is larger than the original one. For example: I have inputted a 1169MB file and the program returned a 1687MB file.
What can be done to solve this issue?
Maybe there are different approaches or variants to compressing a file using Huffman's algorithm that I should be using instead?
struct HuffNode{
    unsigned data;
    struct HuffNode *left;
    struct HuffNode *right;
    struct HuffNode *parent;
    int is_leaf;
};
typedef struct HuffNode HuffNode;

void count_frequency(FILE *fp, unsigned *freq) {
  size_t original_pos = ftell(fp);
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= 0 && ch < 256)
      freq[ch]++;
  }
  fseek(fp, original_pos, SEEK_SET);
}

void construct_huffman(unsigned *freq_in, HuffNode *tree) {
  int count = 256; 
  unsigned freq[256] = {0}; 
  HuffNode *node[256]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) { 
    freq[i] = freq_in[i]; 
    tree[i].data = i; 
    tree[i].left = NULL;
    tree[i].right = NULL;
    tree[i].parent = NULL;
    tree[i].is_leaf = 1; 
    node[i] = &tree[i]; 
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {  
    for (int j = 0; j < 256 - i - 1; j++) {
      if (j + 1 < 256 && (freq[j] < freq[j + 1] || (freq[j] == freq[j+1] && j < j + 1))) { 
        unsigned t = freq[j];
        freq[j] = freq[j + 1];
        freq[j + 1] = t;
        HuffNode *p = node[j]; 
        node[j] = node[j + 1];
        node[j + 1] = p;
      }
    }
  }

  while (count > 1) {
    int pos = 512 - count;
    HuffNode *parent = &tree[pos];
    int i = count - 2, j = count - 1;
    parent->left = node[j]; 
    parent->right = node[i]; 
    node[j]->parent = parent;
    node[i]->parent = parent;
    node[i]->is_leaf = 0;
    node[j]->is_leaf = 0;
    node[i] = parent;
    freq[i] += freq[j]; 
    for (; i > 0 && freq[i] > freq[i - 1]; i--) { 
      unsigned t = freq[i];
      freq[i] = freq[i - 1];
      freq[i - 1] = t;
      HuffNode *p = node[i];
      node[i] = node[i - 1];
      node[i - 1] = p;
    }
    count--;
  }
  node[0]->parent = NULL;
}

void encode_stream(FILE *fin, FILE *fout, HuffNode *tree, unsigned *padding) {
  int n;
  unsigned char ch;
  unsigned char buff = 0, nbuf = 0;
  HuffNode *p;
  unsigned char code[256] = {0};
  while ((n = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    if(n < 0 || n >= 256){
      printf("invalid characters in the file");
      return;
    }
    ch = n;
    p = &tree[ch];
    int code_length = 0;
    while (p->parent) {
      if (p == p->parent->right) {
        code[code_length] = 1;
      }
      p = p->parent;
      code_length++;
    }
    for (int i = code_length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      buff |= code[i] << nbuf;
      nbuf++;
      if (nbuf == 8) {
        fputc(buff, fout);
        nbuf = 0;
        buff = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (nbuf > 0) {
    fputc(buff, fout);
  }
  *padding = 8 - nbuf;
}

void compress_file(FILE *fin, FILE *fout) {

  unsigned freq[256] = {0}, padding = 0; //- хз
  int flag = 0;
  size_t padding_pos;
  HuffNode tree[512]; 
  
  if (flag == 0) {
    count_frequency(fin, freq);
    construct_huffman(freq, tree);
    rewind(fin);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      fwrite(&freq[i], sizeof(unsigned), 1, fout);
    }
    padding_pos = ftell(fout);
    fwrite(&padding, sizeof(unsigned), 1, fout);
    encode_stream(fin, fout, tree, &padding);
    fseek(fout, padding_pos, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&padding, sizeof(unsigned), 1, fout);
    
  }
}

I don't know why it doesn't properly compress the file.

Is the 1169MB file compressable? If you fill it with noise it may be hard to find patterns that can be used to compress it.

What data did you use for test? Do other compressing tools compress it significantly better? I compressed 1383 Mb of random data in base64 and got 1045 Mb with your program. gzip with the same input gives 1051 Mb.

Why the type change with size_t padding_pos; ...  fwrite(&padding, sizeof(unsigned), 1, fout);.  That is dodgy code.

This code is a mess. The "compressed" output is almost entirely 0xff's. First debug it on small examples. I recommend that you write a companion decompressor, as that is the only way to verify that both are working.

Also, I think Huffman encoding stores the hash table (which is often variable in size) in the output file which could explain the compressed file's growth.  Small files are more prone to this.  A zip file having only a 1 byte file is commonly at least 100 bytes.  I think most compression algo's are prone to the pathological scenario of the compressed file being larger than the original due to storing of tables, headers, file directory lists and what not -- and if the input file is small.

&& j < j + 1?

There is a bug in encode_stream(): code is zeroed initially but then only filled with ones. To fix it after if (p == p->parent->right) { code[code_length] = 1; } add else { code[code_length] = 0; }. Or change entire if statement with code[code_length] = (p == p->parent->right);

@dimich i use just a simpr txt file for testing (with a random article). I have fixed the part with 1s and 0s, however i have the same output size as i previously had.

That fix doesn't affect output file size. It allows to decompress data (perhaps, if there are no other bugs in the code).

Before wondering about the size of the output, you need to first make sure that the output is actually a Huffman encoding. It currently is not. The vast majority of the output bytes are 0xff. You should at least look at what's in your output before concluding that it's working.
What you really need to do is write the companion decompressor, and get both working through extensive testing to verify that compression followed by decompression is lossless. Then you can check to see if the output is smaller than the input for something that you expect to be compressible, e.g. English text.
You can greatly reduce the size of the output for small inputs by encoding the Huffman tree, as opposed to sending all 256 frequencies at four bytes each, 1K total. Traverse the tree and write a 1 bit for each branch and a 0 bit followed by the eight bits of the character for a leaf. This tree representation is self-terminating. Follow that with the Huffman-encoded data. For n encoded bytes, that will take 10n-1 bits. At most ~320 bytes if all possible bytes are encoded. Most likely not all are. (There are other even more compact encodings of the code by using Canonical Huffman Codes, but this is an easy one to get started with.)


Huffman's algorithm produces a compressed file that is larger than the original one

Likely the original file is already compressed or just lots of random data.
Not all files are compressible.
If all files are compressible, then one could re-apply compression to the resultant file.  By repeating we could eventually reach a size of 0.
